# IWebBrowserApp.Navigate() How to send Post Data

Tags: c#, shdocvw

I would be very glad if someone could show me a good example of how to send POST data with the Navigate Method, available through `SHDocVw.IWebBrowserApp`.

***Considering for example.***

That the page were we should go is: http://example.com/check.php

And should send the values of two input fields named: username and password.

**EDIT**

I'm attempting with my C# App to use the native Internet Explorer version 7 or higher, available on Windows OS, to send a HTTP Request to a specific URL, passing using the POST method the username and password of an user to a server side page that would handle the HTTP Response.

With `IWebBrowserApp` and the `Navigate` method I'm able to open a new window/instance of Internet Explorer and send it to a specific page (local or in the web), and if specified also send POST data and custom headers.

But the main problem its that i don't know how to write my data into a POST request to be carried by the browser.

I would appreciate help.

Comment: ábio: there's no reason to put "C#" both in the title and in the tags. Please just leave that in the tags.

Comment: @Jonh Saunders: Sure, do you have any suggestion about my problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**I've found how to  order IE to open a webpage and send some POST data.**

- Add a COM Reference named *Microsoft Internet Explorer Controls* to the project.
- Then create the `post string` with the field and its value separated by `&`, and then convert that `string` into a `byte array`.
- And in the end just had to request IE to Navigate to the `url`, and also send the Post Data converted into a `byte array`, and then add the same Header that its added when we submit a form.

Here goes:

```
using SHDocVw; // Don't forget

InternetExplorer IEControl = new InternetExplorer();
IWebBrowserApp IE = (IWebBrowserApp)IEControl;
IE.Visible = true;

// Convert the string into a byte array
ASCIIEncoding Encode = new ASCIIEncoding();
byte[] post = Encode.GetBytes("username=fabio&password=123");

// The destination url
string url = "http://example.com/check.php";

// The same Header that its sent when you submit a form.
string PostHeaders = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

IE.Navigate(url, null, null, post, PostHeaders);
```

---

**NOTE:**

To try if this works. Don't forget that your server side page would have to *write/echo* the Post fields named: username and password.

*PHP Code Example:*

```
<?php
echo $_POST['username'];
echo " ";
echo $_POST['password'];
?>
```

*ASP Code Example:*

```
<%
response.write(Request.Form("username"))
response.write(" " & Request.Form("password"))
%>
```

*And the page would display something like this:*

> fabio 123